# Can a god travel between planes and or dimensions in D&D and can they enter the Prime Material Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, planes, religions-and-deities

In the Forgotten Realms setting, can gods freely travel between dimensions or planes of existence? I don't think they can, or there would be chaos. But maybe a powerful god like Bahamut or an Overgod like AO could?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: By "freely" do you mean "has the power to"?  Or "has no external constraints on doing so"?   Because a god who had the power to, say, go from Arcadia to the Prime Material Plane might be constrained from doing so by agreements with other gods, or merely awareness that they will react, or because appearing the Prime Material Plane will cause the plane itself to react in undesired ways.

Comment: Both basically, can some of them do it, do they have that power? And, if they can, is something stronger stopping them, like Lord AO or some other power? I know that a creature of Good alliances can enter Evil allied planes but they feel uncomfortable and they don't want to stay for long. Is it the same with gods, and what happens when and if they enter the Prime material plane?

Comment: Hmm, i don't know. I know that unofficially, you can do whatever as a DM. Officially, i can't find any record of Gods walking the material plane or traveling freely on others. There are some records of them doing so before the Spellplaque but even then, I am not sure that they did. I think they only manifested aspects of themselves. There was a time that AO cast them all down from the heavens because they stole some plates but that doesn't mean they could travel all over. I am new in D&D, the lore is huge and the wiki isn't the most trustworthy place so i decided to ask people here instead.

Comment: I can't find any official record of Mystra traveling between planes and she is the godess of magic. And even AO who is an Overgod, can't manipulate everything from what I've read. So there are definitely some limits on what they can do.

Comment: Are we only talking about source books or are we including novels? There are plenty of examples of gods going into other planes of existence in the latter.

Comment: which setting are you referring to?

Comment: The answer to the question varies wildly by setting, hence I'm voting to close until a setting is specified.

Comment: @Ulrah for clarity, the gods that you have mentioned in comments (and the Spellplague event) are specific to the Forgotten Realms campaign setting, so it seems most likely that the Forgotten Realms is what you're interested in. You should keep in mind that there have been *many* different campaign settings for the various editions of D&D, and though they frequently share some amount of generic lore, details like what gods there are and what those gods are capable of doing will vary quite significantly by setting. When looking at D&D lore, remember to check which setting it is from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Forgotten Realms

From Faiths and Avatars. (ADnD source, but unfortunately there are very few in depth 5th edition info on gods)

Under the abilities list of Greater Powers

> Planar Travel: Just as they can teleport across space without error, so too can they travel between the various planes of existence at will. These powerful beings cannot, however, travel to the Prime Material Plane.

Although Lord Ao banished the gods to the material plane during the time of trouble, it appears it is the only plane barred to them now.

When it comes to the prime material plane, they are limited to avatars.

> When powers have vital business upon the Prime Material Plane, they must send avatars to act for them. An avatar is simply a manifestation of a deity upon the Prime Material Plane. This manifestation is not nearly as power- ful as a power and is merely a projection of a deity’s power to the Prime Ma- terial Plane. An almost infinitely vast gulf of power lies between the god and the avatar.

Finally, it must be noted that extreme circumstances can allow gods to travel to the prime material plane. Tiamat can successfully return to the material plane with use of her dragon cult, and does so if the heroes fail in the 5th edition adventure Rise of Tiamat.

### Outside of Forgotten Realms

Though somewhat little info is available in 5th edition outside of the Forgotten Realms (as it is the official setting). The Theros campaign setting features and details gods greater than most. A few important things of note from here

> The god Kruphix is able to confine them to Nyx, preventing any direct interaction between the gods and the mortal world.

So at least one god is able to force others to certain planes.

But just as importantly is

> Gods grant their clerics the ability to cast spells, and they can effortlessly duplicate the effect of any spell they could grant (any spell on the cleric spell list, as well as any domain spell from their domains).

Since cleric spells include both [plane shift](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/plane-shift) and [gate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gate). They at the least have the capability of travelling, if not directly prevented from acting by the goddess of destiny.

> Further, the gods of Theros aren’t omnipotent. Although they are physically and magically powerful, ageless, and all but indestructible, their actions are bound by the decrees of Klothys.

Comment: It should be noted that your references to Lord Ao and Tiamat are specific to the Forgotten Realms setting (even though the Rise of Tiamat, like most adventures can be modified by a DM if required). There is no indication that such events are general "rules" in 5th edition

Comment: Added info from outside forgotten realms for you @PJRZ

Comment: Re: Forgotten Realms, more recently the 3e *Faiths and Pantheons* holds that any deity of Divine Rank 6 or higher (so lesser deities and up, distinct from the 1-5 range referred to just as "demigods") is capable of casting *Plane Shift* at will as a spell-like ability, so at that point most of them definitely have the capacity to hop between planes at their leisure. Of course, FR likes to change all the rules about everything with every major edition change, so who knows what the status quo is meant to be now...

Comment: @Daveman Apparently i was indeed interested at the forgotten realms setting, yes. Thank you for answering and everyone else for helping. I guess, at the the end of the day, it depends on the DM and the setting. That's good for me.